How can I resolve Error: Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault?
I have a pretty large project that I've been working on and have recently encountered this error on both IOS and Android:
Error: Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from Project/client/index.js: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules ../../../../node_modules
I have been trying to resolve it for the past few weeks with no resolve. Additionally, my partner working on the same project is not encountering this issue when running on our main branch which has been baffling to us.
I have tried the following:

Deleting and reinstalling the dependencies


npm install -f
cd ios && pod install


Reconfiguring Xcode's build environment


Cleaning the project
Deleting derived data


Updating the related dependancies


@babel/runtime


Watchman


Uninstalling + reinstalling
Stopping and restarting the service
Killing watches


Recloning the app from github (same version my partner is working off of)

Here is my package.json file (proprietary info has been removed):
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Client side application",
  "license": "CC-BY-ND-4.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "check-dependencies": "rnx-align-deps",
    "fix-dependencies": "rnx-align-deps --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/generative-ai": "^0.16.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.22.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.7.7",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.74.86",
    "@react-native/virtualized-lists": "^0.74.86",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.74.0",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.25.1",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "use-latest-callback": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.25.3",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.74.86",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.0",
    "@rnx-kit/align-deps": "^2.5.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^9.8.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "rnx-kit": {
    "kitType": "app",
    "alignDeps": {
      "requirements": [
        "react-native@0.74"
      ],
      "capabilities": [
        "animation",
        "babel-preset-react-native",
        "core",
        "core-android",
        "core-ios",
        "core/metro-config",
        "datetime-picker",
        "gestures",
        "jest",
        "navigation/native",
        "react",
        "react-test-renderer",
        "safe-area",
        "screens",
        "storage"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Please let us know if anyone has tips that may help!
